# Python create a specific dict from three list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have three list, I want to convert into a specific dict

```
A = ["a", "b"]
B = ["10", "20"]
C = ["key1", "key2"]
```

I want a dict like that

```
"key1": {
  "name": "a",
  "age": 10
},
"key2": {
    "name": "b",
    "age": 20
  }
```

I try different way by different step, but I don't get this dict

```
for key in A:
  dict_A["name"].append(key)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Created a nested dictionary from three separate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100170/created-a-nested-dictionary-from-three-separate-lists)

Answer (score 7):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
res = {key: {'name': name, 'age': age} for key, name, age in zip(C, A, B)}
```

This gives:

```
{'key1': {'age': '10', 'name': 'a'}, 'key2': {'age': '20', 'name': 'b'}}
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) allows you to aggregate elements from each iterable by index.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `zip` then you can use `enumerate` as given below:

```
print ({v:{"name": A[k],"age": B[k]} for k, v in enumerate(C)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In[1]:  {c: {'name': a, 'age': b} for a, b, c in zip(A, B, C)}
Out[1]: {'key1': {'name': 'a', 'age': '10'}, 'key2': {'name': 'b', 'age': '20'}}
```

Comment: A code only answers is not preferable in SO, at least try to describe to the OP/Readers what your code do.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for a,b,c in zip(A, B, C):
    your_dict[c] = {"name" : a, "age": b}
```