# Create a nested dictionary that groups the elements in three ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a dictionary which contains the information in three ndarrays of the same dimension, such as:

```
import numpy as np
name = np.array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'])
pid = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8])
dev = np.array([11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31, 11, 42, 31, 51, 52, 61, 71, 72, 73, 81])
```

The desired output should be something like:

```
 alldevs = {
        'a': {
            1: [11, 12]
            2: [21, 22, 22]
            3: [31]
            }
        'b': {
            4: [11, 42, 31],
            5: [51, 52],
            6: [61]
            }
        'c': {
            7: [71, 72, 73],
            8: [81]
            }
        }
```

So far I've got:

```
allDevs = {a:{b:[c]} for a,b,c in zip(name,pid,dev)}
```

which gives only the last of each group, but doesn't group all the values in `dev` which share `name` and `pid`:

```
 {'a': {3: [31]}, 'b': {6: [61]}, 'c': {8: [81]}}
```

I've found this [Created a nested dictionary from three separate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100170/created-a-nested-dictionary-from-three-separate-lists) but it doesn't do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group elements from arrays (assuming they are sorted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby 

name = np.array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'])
pid = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8])
dev = np.array([11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31, 11, 42, 31, 51, 52, 61, 71, 72, 73, 81])

alldevs = {}
for (n, p), g in groupby(zip(name, pid, dev), lambda k: (k[0], k[1])):
    for _, _, d in g:
        alldevs.setdefault(n, {}).setdefault(p, []).append(d)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(alldevs)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': {1: [11, 12], 2: [21, 22, 23], 3: [31]},
 'b': {4: [11, 42, 31], 5: [51, 52], 6: [61]},
 'c': {7: [71, 72, 73], 8: [81]}}
```

Comment: That works great, and what if the arrays are not sorted?

Comment: @acb You can do `name.sort()`, the same for `pid`, assuming you want to group by these two arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to see how the sausage is made:

```
allDevs = dict()
for a,b,c in zip(name,pid,dev):
    if a not in allDevs:
        allDevs[a] = dict()
    if b not in allDevs[a]:
        allDevs[a][b] = [c]
    else:
        allDevs[a][b].append(c)
```

Comment: I like this answer because I can see the process so I upvoted it as well, but accepted the previous one because its fewer lines of code. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a dict comprehension using `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
{n: {p: list(map(itemgetter(2), d)) for p, d in groupby(g, itemgetter(1))} 
        for n, g in groupby(zip(name, pid, dev), itemgetter(0))}
```

---

Results:

```
{'a': {1: [11, 12], 2: [21, 22, 23], 3: [31]}, 
 'b': {4: [11, 42, 31], 5: [51, 52], 6: [61]}, 
 'c': {7: [71, 72, 73], 8: [81]}}
```